# How do I make the input box bigger?

Tags: html, input

I'm trying to make this comment box bigger but can't seem to figure out how. Just wondering if you guys could help. This is what I've tried to do.

```html
<form action="" target="_blank">
  <br>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">
  <br><br>
  Comment:<br>
  <input type="text" rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" value="">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`textarea`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) attribute for that kind of larger, multi-line text field.

```html
<form action="" target="_blank">
  <br>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">
  <br><br>
  Comment:<br>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment"></textarea>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```